# C# Custom property value lost when build

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem with a custom class. What happens is that it loses its value after the project is compiled. Can someone help me?

I have the following custom class:

```
public class DataGridViewTextBoxColumnCustom : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
   public bool EstaDisponibleParaFiltro { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that in the form designer, when I add a column of type `DataGridViewTextBoxCOlumnCustom` to the [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=net-5.0) control and set its property `ThisAvailableParaFilter` to `true`, the value always returns to `false`. I hope you can give me a hand with this.

EDIT 1:

This is my custom class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Solucion.Presentacion.controles
{
    public class DataGridViewTextBoxColumnCustom : System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    {
        public bool EstaDisponibleParaFiltro { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the `DataGridView` control I add one `ColumnType`, `DataGridViewTextBoxColumnCustom`, and set `EstaDisponibleParaFiltro` property to `true`:

[image]

But when I click **Ok**, the property always returns to `false`. I need to fix it.

Comment: Don't talk about your code, show your code in the question.

Comment: Hi Jeremy Lakeman, i edit post. Check please.

Comment: "When you derive from ... and add new properties to the derived class, be sure to override the Clone method to copy the new properties during cloning operations" [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customize-cells-and-columns-in-the-datagrid-by-extending-behavior?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) I assume that applies to `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` as well?

Comment: 'the value is always returned to false' --- do you mean, in the designer, the value automatically reset to `false`?

Comment: Yes, Lei Yang ... the value always set False (never retains its value)

Comment: Do not add words like "solved", "updated", etc. to the title. The site already has other ways to indicate those statuses.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i was able to fix the problem as follows:

1. Adding the following attributes to the property:

> ```
> [Browsable(true)]
> [DefaultValue(false)]
> [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
> public bool EstaDisponibleParaFiltro { get; set; }
> ```

2. Overriding the clone method:

> ```
> public override object Clone()
> {
>    var clone = (DataGridViewTextBoxColumnCustom)base.Clone();
>    clone.EstaDisponibleParaFiltro = this.EstaDisponibleParaFiltro;
>    return clone;
> }
> ```

3. That's it, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: The key is in `Clone` method.